# Python bound method instance error

Tags: python, methods, error-handling

I am trying to implement a recursive function in a class like:

```
class R:
    def A(self):
        if flag:
             return self.value
        else:
             ret=0
             for c in childs:
                 ret += c.A()
             return ret
r = R()
print r.A()
```

I am getting the message:

```
<bound method R.A of <R.R instance at 0x7fa1c1487248>>
```

I am not looking for the string representation of the method call, I want to print the result of the recursive calculation.

Comment: That's not an error. That's the string representation of a bound method of an instance of a class.

Comment: That's not an error, that's a representation of a method. It probably means you are returning `self.A` somewhere. Your code is incomplete, what are `flag`, `childs` and `self.value`?

Comment: Flag is a boolean indicating a leaf node. Childs is a list of child nodes. Self.value is a value which is only set in leaf nodes (flag=True).

Comment: Oh, and I forgot that I am making a call: `r=R() print r.A()`

Comment: The code you show us wouldn't return `self.A` at any point, you missed something when simplifying your code.

Comment: Side note: your `ret…` block is usually written `return sum(c.A() for c in childs)` (I guess you meant `self.children`, though). Python is much more expressive than C, and you should try to make use of this as much as possible.

Comment: There are two possible ways you can get that output from a code similar to what you posted.
1) at some point you assign R.A to self.value instead of calling it or
2) the last two lines are actually r = R(); print r.A [without the ()].

Comment: @Bakuriu: I think I made the call without braces, thus, r.A. The code works now flawless. I experienced the flaw yesterday, but I could not post it immediately. Thanx!